# Hand pain in the first lumbrical muscle due to golf, why?

Tags: golf, injuries

Let's investigate the pain in the first lumbrical due to repetitive golf swings with backswing where the support hand experience the pain. It can be repetitive injury, too weak muscles or poor technique. If you are left, then the pain is in the first lumbrical of the left hand. If you are right, then the pain is in the first lumbrical of the right hand.

[image]

I first doubted "not tight enough golf grip where hands not as package" and then "not proper backswing" but [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNh6mGTfK-w&feature=youtube_gdata_player) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G32adMjV-KQ&feature=youtube_gdata_player) confirmed me otherwise. So I am still in the starting point: I cannot understand why my first lumbrical becomes painful after repetition: I am not sure whether it is because my hand muscles are not yet familiar with the stress or some other reason. First lumbrical is connected to the muscle "flexor digitorum profundus." Tension in that muscle may cause pain to the hand. Poor warm-up of the hand muscles? Or some other reason?

> **How do you alleviate the pain in the first lumbrical due to golf?**

**Helper questions**

> 1. How do you warm up the small hand muscles in golf?
> 2. What have been the reasons for the pain in the first lumbrical with you in golf?

Comment: Curious...where do you get your diagnoses? Outside of being diagnosed with sciatic back pain from playing golf, most of my ephemeral injuries have been a sore knee or ankle...not going any further to pinpoint.

Comment: @edmastermind29 Yes and the diagnoses: I know the anatomy and I know the muscles related to sports. Then I consult experts with specific questions and usually they are able to help me. It is of course good if you have classrooms of medical students/grads who exercise same/related sports as you and your peers. It is highly motivational to learn new stuff, smart people want to learn new stuff all the time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the pain in the first lumbrical by the following changes to my swing. My swing was diagnosed with two Pro coaches so I am confident about the swing getting far better now:

> 1. tight grip where the thumb firmly aligned along the club (helps in backswing due to wrists so not getting any space between thumb and the club)
> 2. club must point to the direction of the hit during the backswing
> 3. backswing is done also by wrists so that the main hand is straight

so the club won't wobble over the lumbrical 1st during the swing, the cause for the pain.